# Outputing the result of a function from another function in Scala

Tags: list, scala, set

I have a function that should return List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] as output and I coded a function 'a' that returns the (Int,Int) part and another function 'b' that returns the Set[Int] part. How can I call the function 'b' inside 'a' to sort of concatenate both results to return the final List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] result? Thanks

```
def a(): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] = 
{ 
   lis.zipWithIndex flatMap 
   {
     row=> row._1.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 1) map 
    {
      col => (row._2, col._2) 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't ever told us what the arguments to `b` should be, so again, I've guessed what they should be:

```
def a(): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] = 
{ 
   lis.zipWithIndex flatMap 
   {
     row=> row._1.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 1) map 
    {
      col => (row._2, col._2, b(row._2, col._2)) 
    } 
  } 
}
```